# Can't start tomcat as service in redhat

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, service

I'm new to Linux but having spent a whole day I Installed Java and Tomcat. My goal is to host an App with this Linux box. I know it all works fine from my windows based machine, but it is my laptop so I'm planning to use the Linux Box as my dedicated server.

[I am following this tutorial .](http://www.davidghedini.com/pg/entry/install_tomcat_7_on_centos) From this tutorial I have executed the following command :

```
cd /etc/init.d 
vi tomcat 
#!/bin/bash  
# description: Tomcat Start Stop Restart  
# processname: tomcat  
# chkconfig: 234 20 80  
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05  
export JAVA_HOME  
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH  
export PATH  
CATALINA_HOME=/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.29  

case $1 in  
start)  
sh $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh  
;;   
stop)     
sh $CATALINA_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh  
;;   
restart)  
sh $CATALINA_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh  
sh $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh  
;;   
esac      
exit 0  
chmod 755 tomcat
chkconfig --add tomcat 
chkconfig --level 234 tomcat on 
chkconfig --list tomcat 
service tomcat start
```

After this command , tomcat is started at port 8082 . But when I restart pc , the tomcat is not started with boot of PC .

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you use Red Hat you can use `systemd` for services.

Create a file `/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking

Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05
Environment=CATALINA_PID=/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.29/temp/tomcat.pid
Environment=CATALINA_HOME=/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.29
Environment=CATALINA_BASE=/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.29
Environment='CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC'
Environment='JAVA_OPTS=-Duser.timezone=UTC -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom'

ExecStart=/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.29/bin/startup.sh
ExecStop=/bin/kill -15 $MAINPID

User=tomcat
Group=tomcat

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I specified the script to start after `syslog` and `network` are enabled.
As we can see systemd handles the tomcat as a daemon and kills the PID.
With `User` and `Group` we specify the user and the group that the process should be run as.
Systemd will handle the `upstart` process and kill it using the PID.

To enable it to run then issue:

```
systemctl enable tomcat
systemctl start tomcat
```

Comment: Please tell what is wrong in my script / procedure .

Comment: Try  chkconfig
sudo /sbin/chkconfig --add tomcat
sudo /sbin/chkconfig --list tomcat
sudo /sbin/chkconfig tomcat on

Comment: Note: Forwarding request to 'systemctl enable tomcat.service'.
Failed to issue method call: Bad message

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this command instead:

```
sudo systemctl enable tomcat
```